# What is the Python base class?

Tags: python, class, object

What is the base class in python or base Object? For example we have base exception for the exceptions, but do we have a base class for the classes or objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean by *the* base class? Classes can have arbitrary base classes. ``object`` is the common ancestor of all builtin classes *by convention* and all custom classes *by consequence* (as they must inherit from a builtin class) but one could in principle create a new builtin class that does not (pretend to) derive from ``object``.

Comment: I meant the masterclass of all classes. How would you create a class that is not derived from object? Built-in and custom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `object` class.

You can check this by using [`inspect.getmro`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmro) which returns the entire class hierarchy of a type.

example:

```py
import inspect

class A: # inherits nothing
  pass

class B(A): # inherits A
  pass

print(inspect.getmro(B))
print(inspect.getmro(A))
```

Output:

```
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```